# Complaint vs Complain (AmE pronunciation)

Tags: pronunciation

My question is about the pronunciation of the T of the word complaint.

On one hand, I work for a company where I deal with different nationalities. Some Egyptians, Indians, and other nationalities don't pronounce the T. Also, I learned that people in the USA don't pronounce the T when it comes after the N. That's why I  think I should pronounce it.

On the other hand, This [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/complaint) pronounce the T.

If they both are pronounced the same way, what about writing? Can I use "complain" as a noun and a verb?

Comment: Maybe some Egyptians, Indians, and other nationalities don't pronounce the T, but *they're not native Anglophones*. I'm not aware of any truly native "dialect" where this might happen, unless maybe you're thinking of the way people like me (somewhat "Cockney" BrE) might well enunciate a glottal stop instead of an actual /t/ in many contexts (particularly, before a vowel, as in *I've had a complainʔ about your work*). For all practical purposes you should just forget about this and assume "T-less" ***complain*** is always a verb.

Comment: *"Also, I learned that people in the USA don't pronounce the T when it comes after the N."*  I'm not sure where you heard this, but it is not true.  *complain* and *complaint* are definitely pronounced differently everywhere in the USA that I know of.

Comment: complaint is a noun; complain is a verb. advise is a verb; advice is a noun. Difference in pronunciation matters. AmE speakers most certainly use the t in complaint. Whatever makes you think they do not? "We made a complaint to the company". "We made a complain." sounds completely wrong and non-fluent in the language...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about the validity of a "mispronunciation" that doesn't actually occur among native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So you mean that the T should be pronounced. That answers my question. Thank you,

Comment: @stangdon what about (international, internet, advantage, ...etc.)? You drop the T in those words, right? From your comment, I can see that *complaint* doesn't follow this rule. Thank you,

Comment: @Lambie I just wanted to make sure beause it seems that I was surrounded by people who pronounce it wrong. Thank you,

Comment: Those words you list (international,internet and advantage) do not contain a final nt. The dropping of t's which one sometimes hears (innernational), is not relevant [oh, there's another one] to complaint. There are tons of adjectives ending in nt: relevant,competent, silent, cogent, etc. The nt is always heard unless the person has a speech defect....

Comment: @stangdon many people render the *t* as a glottal stop, which is often inaudible.  They will shorten the vowel, however, so the two words are still pronounced differently even if there's no audible *t.*

Comment: @Lambie many Americans, myself included, render the /t/ in a final /nt/ as a (frequently inaudible) glottal stop.  But we shorten the vowel (and the nasal consonant) so the words are still pronounced distinctly (similar to the shortening in "writer," where the medial consonant is essentially the same as that in "rider").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Complain" is a verb, period.

> I want to **complain**.

"Complaint" is a noun, period.

> I want to register a **complaint**.

There should be a clear and noticeable difference in how these are pronounced, although it might take a while to hear this with various regional accents.

However, if "complaint" is followed by a word that begins with a "t" sound, then (depending on the person's *diction*) the two might blend into each other:

> I want to make a **complaint to** the manager. ("I wanna makea complainto the manager")

Comment: Right,it comes out as complainto.....:)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that many American English speakers frequently do not pronounce the *t* at the end of *complaint.*  At least, they do not pronounce it as a plosive.  Rather, they [glottalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Glottalization) it to some extent.

Speakers who do this, however, will generally shorten the vowel of the second syllable, removing any ambiguity between *complain* and *complaint.*  In writing, it would never be correct to omit the final *t* from the noun *complaint.*